# String replace using javascript like 123 and 321 to abc and cba

Tags: javascript

On my page: 123 and 321, when Try it click it shows like: abc and cba. How i done this?? my code:

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
        var res = str.replace(/1/g, "a");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="demo">123 and 321</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have one replace working already. What's stopping you from doing more of the same?

Comment: `var res = str.replace(/([0-9])/g, function(d) { return String.fromCharCode(96+d*1); });`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial solution to the problem.

It's not clear if you're actually after something more generic in reality, but this solves the specific problem stated in the question, by adding more (simplistic) replace functions.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
        var res = str.replace(/1/g, "a");
        res = res.replace(/2/g, "b");
        res = res.replace(/3/g, "c");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="demo">123 and 321</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How i replace multiple value using one replace method??

Comment: Look into http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [String.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Iterate over the characters and if the character in a number from `1-9`, update it to corresponding `alphabet` else add the character as it is.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
      if(charCode >= 49 && charCode <= 57) res += String.fromCharCode(charCode + 48)
      else res += str[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">123 and 321</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```